# update label text in for loop

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm working on a shopping cart GUI. I have a list called my_order, which stores the information I get from the user. I want to update label text in a for loop so I can print all the elements of my_order list. Here's my code:

```
class PaymentScreen(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PaymentScreen, self).__init__()
        loadUi("paymentscreen.ui",self)
        self.gobackbutton.clicked.connect(self.goback)
        self.basket.setText("{}".format(my_order)) #the output looks like ["burger","fries"] and I dont want that
```

I'm trying to print all the elements one under the another instead of that list view. I looked for the similar cases but couldn't find the solution.

I want the output to look like this:

```
burger
fries
```

How can I do that?

I want to update label text

Comment: you don't have any for loop in your code. In order to `update label text in for loop` you need... well, a for loop.

Comment: I know I don't have a for loop in my post.  I gave an example that the output I don't want to get :/

Comment: oh, so the example you gave is what you don't want to get? Cold you post an example of what you actually want to get then?

Comment: You should really try to put more efforts in trying to explain what you want to do. "I want to update label text in a for loop" has **absolutely nothing to do** with what you actually wanted. Or PyQt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no expert in Python GUI but i am good in python programming and I assume you want the string inside setText to be a multiline string. I could help with that.

You can use something line this:

`self.basket.setText("\n".join(my_order))`

Comment: Thank youuu. That's what I was trying to do. Worked perfectly <3

Comment: what? so you want a string as a multiline and to ask that you write "update label text in for loop"?